# problems with re and numbers

Tags: python, regex, parsing

```
def de_punctuate(xs):
    return re.findall(r"[\w']+(?:-[\w']+)*", xs)

numbers = partial(re.search, r'[0,9]')

def no_numbers(xs):
    return filterfalse(numbers, xs)

def string2filter(xs):
    return no_numbers(de_punctuate(xs))

for d in data:
    print(d)
    print(list(string2filter(d)))
```

output:

```
Nordmann brukte mobilen i ett døgn i Afrika - må ut med 137.000 kroner
['Nordmann', 'brukte', 'mobilen', 'i', 'ett', 'døgn', 'i', 'Afrika', 'må', 'ut', 'med', '137', 'kroner']

400.000 japanere evakueres fra flom
['japanere', 'evakueres', 'fra', 'flom']

Utvist i 2009 - nå siktet for overfallsvoldtekt i 2011
['Utvist', 'i', 'nå', 'siktet', 'for', 'overfallsvoldtekt', 'i']

Selvmordsangrep mot afghansk bryllupsfest - Minst 22 drepte
['Selvmordsangrep', 'mot', 'afghansk', 'bryllupsfest', 'Minst', '22', 'drepte']
```

I am confused about why the output is not consistent with regard to the numbers. There should not be any. In some cases this is correct, but then for other they are still there. 
see output 1 and 4.

any ideas?

i want to test each `word` in case there are errors like: `this3`

could I include a numerical search in the first re-expressions, so I could not have to do a double pass?

the answer is:

```
def stripsplit(xs):
    """ return a list, excluding numbers and punctuation (except joining hyphens) """
    return re.findall(r"[a-zA-ZåøæÅØÆ']+(?:-[a-zA-ZåøæÅØÆ']+)*", xs)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search for numbers, instead of `r'[0,9]'` you should be using `'[0-9]'` or `'\d'`.

(`[0,9]` matches on '0' or ',' or '9', which isn't what you meant)

**Edit:** `\w` is the equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Why not just use `[a-zA-Z']` instead?

Comment: well that worked! would you recommend including this in the first re.findall?

Comment: as in, how would I add that to `re.findall(r"[\w']+(?:-[\w']+)*", xs)`

Comment: could I just add the special chars to like  a-zA-ZåøæÅØÆ ?